# Date List/Array to Human Readable Month Range in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

The goal of this solution was to generate human readable date range (e.g: Jan 19 - May 19) from an array of dates.

**Input:**

```
$dates = ['2019-10-20', '2019-09-20', '2019-11-20', '2019-01-20','2020-02-20','2020-03-20','2020-04-20','2020-01-20'];
```

**Output**

```
Jan 2019 - Jan 2019, Sep 2019 - Nov 2019, Jan 2020 - Apr 2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
<?php
    function list_to_human_month_range($dates){
        usort($dates, function($a,$b){
            return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
        });
        $gap = [];
        $gap_id = 0;
        $fd = $dates[0];
        foreach ($dates as $key => $date) {
            if($key>0){ $fd =$dates[$key-1]; }
            $to = new DateTime($date);
            $from = new DateTime($fd);
            $interval = $from->diff($to);
            $diff_in_months = $interval->format('%m');
            if($diff_in_months>1){
                $gap_id += 1;
            }
            $gap[$gap_id][] = $date;
        }
        $final = [];
        foreach ($gap as $key => $value) {
            $final[] = date('M Y', strtotime(current($value))) . date(' - M Y', strtotime(end($value)));
        }
        return implode(", ", $final);
    }
?>
```

**How this thing works?**

1. Sort's date array
2. separates dates by month interval
3. usages first and last value from separated data and formats it using php date function